# Create a MS Team's Channel using Shell Script or Shell commands

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there any way we can create a team's channel using shell commands?

I have gone through the below documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

You can create MS Teams channel using PowerShell script as below:

```
New-TeamChannel
   -GroupId <String>
   -DisplayName <String>
   [-Description <String>]
   [-MembershipType <String>]
   [-Owner <String>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Example 1: Create a standard channel with display name as "Architecture"

```
New-TeamChannel -GroupId 126b90a5-e65a-4fef-98e3-d9b49f4acf12 -DisplayName "Architecture"
```

Example 2: Create a private channel with display name as "Engineering"

```
New-TeamChannel -GroupId 126b90a5-e65a-4fef-98e3-d9b49f4acf12 -DisplayName "Engineering" -MembershipType Private
```